# Cross-build sbt plugins against different launcher versions?

Tags: scala, plugins, sbt

Is there a convenient way to automatically **cross-build a sbt 0.10/0.11.x plugin** against multiple sbt versions? I guess this is somewhat a chicken - egg problem but maybe someone has an idea how to solve this.

Note, I'm not looking for a scala cross-build, the question only targets sbt-plugins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't really a convenient built-in way, no.  I think it would be straightforward to write such a command.  However, the plan is for binary compatibility within 0.12.x to make this less of a problem.

Comment: Great. I'll look forward to the 0.12 release, seems that version brings a couple of nice changes.

Answer (score 4):

There's this:

https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-cross-building

Of course the first problem you will run to is that your plugin needs to primarily build with versions of sbt and scala supported by *that* plugin.